# SharePoint 2010 Client Object Model - 401 on SubSite but not root

Tags: development, client-object-model, 401

I am trying to use the CSOM to access data from a root site, then loop through its subsites to get into files that are stored in its lists.  When I go to create the ClientContext, it works fine with the root URL, but when I use one of the subsites' URL's, I get a 401 when I hit ExecuteQuery().

```
using (var clientContext = new ClientContext(rootURL))
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Establishing connection...");

            var userName = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["userName"];
            var domain = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["domain"];
            var password = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["pwd"];
            var credentials = new NetworkCredential(userName, password, domain);
            clientContext.Credentials = credentials;

            _clientContext = clientContext;

            var spContext2 = new SharePointClientDataContext(clientContext);

            ClientContext newContext = new ClientContext(subsiteURL);
            var allLists = newContext.Web.Lists;
            newContext.Load(allLists);
            newContext.ExecuteQuery();

            try
            {
...
```

The code fails at `newContext.ExecuteQuery()`.  Any ideas why I would run into 401's at the subsite level, but not the root level?

It is also worth noting that this DOES work locally, but I am currently trying to run this from my host OS to access files from my VM.

Answer (score 0):

My problem was that I was not re-setting the credentials for the new ClientContext, so I just needed to do:

```
newContext.Credentials = credentials;
```

After doing that, it worked fine.